# What is the next number in this sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Can you determine the next number in the below sequence?

$1.0 , 4.0 , 6.9 , 9.0 , 10.8 , 12.0 , 14.0 , 16.0 , ?$

**Bonus:** Determine the next number that comes after '**?**'

Note: I'll post some hints if nobody gets the answer.

**Hint #1:** You won't get the relationship between the numbers by calculating.

**Hint #2:** These numbers have some relationship with science.

Comment: Too broad; too many answers. Voted to close.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's just a sequence. We could throw guesses at the wall all day and by the end be no closer to a solution. This type of puzzle is generally disliked on puzzling.SE, and moreover disliked as a whole.

Comment: From seeing the answer: This is a puzzle where you either recognize the pattern or you don't. You can't get anywhere by thinking by about it.

Comment: @xnor And it won't even be on OEIS (I think) because it isn't an *integer* sequence...

Comment: @mdc32 It also depends on how you round the numbers...

Comment: @RobWatts Never mind. http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+4%2C+7%2C+9%2C+11&language=english&go=Search but you'd have to round

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers represent

> Atomic weights

The next 5 numbers are

> 19.0, 20.2, 23.0, 24.3, and 27.0